# Sharepoint Custom Search Results Page using FullTextSQLQuery

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a customized search that displays results based on my FullTextSQLQuery results (i.e. user types 'Foo' clicks Search, my server-side code performs a FullTextSQLQuery bringing back PDF documents that contain 'Foo' in its text).

My question is what will I need to do after getting the results from my query in order to display the results to the user?  Will I need to provide my own results aspx page or does SP have something that is out-of-box that I can use to perhaps pass my results along to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything OOTB, but this is a simple matter of transforming the XML results into HTML using an XSL.

Comment: Sorry, what XML results?  Are you saying I should serialize the ResultTable I get back into XML or something else?

Comment: You can get results either as datatable or as XML, take a deeper look into the API